# method reference for instance method from static method

Tags: java, method-reference

Sorry for not clearly the title, i'm still new to this and even English.

```
Collections.sort(aList, (s1, s2) -> Float.compare(s1.getAFloat(), s2.getAFloat()));
```

As above, can I use method references? if `s1` and `s2` are `Float`s and they don't use get-a-float method then things become easier:

```
Collections.sort(aList,Float::compare);
```

But with `s1.getAFloat()` I don't know how to use method reference or even possible to use it, thanks for answer!

Comment: You can visit tutorials of how method reference works. http://java8tips.readthedocs.io/en/latest/funcinterfaces.html#method-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Look into the following code.

```
List<Float> aList = Arrays.asList(5.2f, 9.7f);
Collections.sort(aList, (s1, s2) -> Float.compare(s1, s2));
Collections.sort(aList, Float::compare);
```

If your list elements were directly of `Float` type then you would have used *method-reference*.

If elements are not of `Float` type then you can do like this.

```
List<String> aList2 = Arrays.asList("5.2f", "9.7f");  
aList2.stream().map(Float::valueOf).sorted(Float::compare)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Collections.sort(aList, Comparator.comparing(ItemType::getAFloat));
```

And if the retrieved type aren't sortable already, you can give an additional comparator to `comparing`.